# problem running xp_cmdshell when Application Name set in connection string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xp-cmdshell

I have an app on 10 or so servers that runs a few xp_cmdshell statements against MSSQL 2008. It works fine on all the servers except for one. To make things worse, I can run all the commands in SQL Management Studio, but in the app, they don't work. I even made a temporary app to test and it works fine! But in the deployed app, I get a simple SQL error "Access Denied". I have narrowed it down to the connection string, if I include the application name

```
Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3};Application Name=TheGroovyApp
```

It throws access denied only when calling xp_cmdshell, normal SQL statements works fine. But if I remove the application name

```
Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3}
```

It works fine for both normal SQL statements and calls to xp_cmdshell. The strange thing is, its only happening on one of the ten servers. The only difference being that the server has SP1 and the others do not.

@@VERSION returns

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)
```

I am thinking that there is some sort of authentication that can be granted to applications, but I cant seem to find anything. I can replicate it in SQL Managment Studio by adding

```
Application Name=TheGroovyApp
```

to the Additional Connection Parameters tab on the Connect to Database Engine dialog when you create a new query or change its connection.

The simple test statement I use is

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR F:\SomeDirectory'
```

If anyone could shed some light on what is happening it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

OK after a bit more investigation its even more confusing.

If I set the Application Name to the following which is the default for .Net connections, it works fine.

```
Application Name=".Net SqlClient Data Provider"
```

I can run xp_subdirs without any problems no matter which settings I use

```
EXEC master..xp_subdirs 'F:\SomeDirectory'
```

Now this is where it gets really weird. The first two fail, but the last one succeeds with the application name being set to my application name. But only if its xp_cmdshell that get called, xp_subdirs works with all three.

**With Application Name in connection set**

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR F:\SomeDirectory' - Fails
master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR F:\SomeDirectory' - Fails
xp_cmdshell 'DIR F:\SomeDirectory' - Works
EXEC master..xp_subdirs 'F:\SomeDirectory' - Works
master..xp_subdirs 'F:\SomeDirectory' - Works
xp_subdirs 'F:\SomeDirectory' - Works
```

**With Application Name not set in connection**

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR F:\SomeDirectory' - Works
master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR F:\SomeDirectory' - Works
xp_cmdshell 'DIR F:\SomeDirectory' - Works
EXEC master..xp_subdirs 'F:\SomeDirectory' - Works
master..xp_subdirs 'F:\SomeDirectory' - Works
xp_subdirs 'F:\SomeDirectory' - Works
```

**The error returned in the query messages area in SQLMS when it fails**

```
Msg 10011, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Access denied.
```

This error message is only happening on the one server, I cannot replicate this on any others.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something as simple as the total length of your execution string?  In all your examples, the longer one fails while the shorter one succeeds.  How long is your overall string, and how does that compare to the length of your variable?

Comment: I am sure it is not the length, SQLMS does exactly the same thing when I set the application name in the connection window. I would also get a incomplete SQL error instead of the "Access Denied". It would also have the same problem with the xp_subdirs which it doesn't. I'll modify my question to include them. I have run the test on several test SQL servers which are R2 SP1 and its fine on those. It is only this one server that has the problem.

Comment: Is this server having the same SQL version / Service Pack installed as others (ones that are not having the issue) ? Also, is the account privileged same on other servers ? There must be something different on this... as you are experiencing issues with this particular server.

Comment: One other production server is R2 SP1, the others are still R2 to be upgraded to SP1. But it works fine on all of them them. The test servers are R2 SP1 and it works fine on them as well. So it seems that the version is not the issue. I have two sysadmin accounts that I am testing with, one is a windows account and the other a SQL account. Both have the problem on this one server. But only if the application name is set in the connection. They are fine otherwise. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: What are the other differences -- however trivial -- between the two servers?

Comment: What does setting "Application Name" do?

Comment: What command is the production app running via xp_cmdshell?

Comment: My only other guess would be to have a look at your language/locality and collation settings.  Make sure the problem server has the same settings as your other ones.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no differences between this server and the others, they are all running on the same type of servers (hardware VM) out on each site, except for the big gun at head office which is used by multiple systems. Application Name is used to identify which app when looking at the activity monitor. As we have several apps, .Net SqlClient Data Provider does not tells us much when we need to trouble shoot. So we are adding the app name to each apps connection string as an aid.

Comment: @Colin'tHart the commands that I run are as follows String.Format("EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'del {0}'", exportDbLocal),
String.Format("EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp {0} out {1} -T -N'", fullTempTable, exportDbLocal),
String.Format("EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'move {0} {1}'", exportDbLocal, exportMdNetwork) Basically, delete local file -> bcp dump to local -> move file to network share, My app can then continue to process said file without SQL. It fails on the first one. Normally, a simple result would be a list of any messages successful or not, but it does not get that far, it throws exception.

Comment: Please try to replace `xp_cmdshell 'DIR F:\SomeDirectory'` with `xp_cmdshell 'echo %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%'` and tell us if there is a difference when application name is or is not set (and when using\not using the `master` prefix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stab in the dark, but after we installed SQL Server 2008 SP2 on the server, the problem no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0):

the database(s) associated with the application should be trustworthy in order to access the machine's command line.

Try

```
select name,is_trustworthy_on from sys.databases;
```

if your target database is not trustworthy then:

```
alter database db_name set trustworthy on;
```

but beware the compromise to security

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, msdb was the only one that was trustworthy on all the servers, but I changed it anyway to test if it would work. No Luck.