# Can I drop and recreate a system extended stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having a problem with one of my servers where I cannot execute xp_cmdshell under certain conditions. The full problem can be found here [problem running xp_cmdshell when Application Name set in connection string](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40284/problem-running-xp-cmdshell-when-application-name-set-in-connection-string)

I want to see if dropping and recreating it will fix it (on a test server first). I'm grabbing at straws here.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't drop and re-create xp_cmdshell. It's not even its own procedure, but part of a library in xpstar.dll (or at least it was at one point). And I am extremely skeptical that, even if you could re-create this procedure, that would fix the problem you're having.

Maybe instead of banging your head against this problem with xp_cmdshell, you should just bite the bullet and implement the functionality you need in CLR. Or perform the tasks you need outside of SQL Server altogether.

Comment: I use xp_cmdshell to execute bcp for bulk imports and exports of data. Are SQL CLR objects capable of doing the same bulk table operations speedy fashion like bcp?

Comment: Sure, and so is a background process. Why must the BCP ultimately be initiated by T-SQL? What event occurs that tells T-SQL to call xp_cmdshell to call BCP? Couldn't this just log an entry in a queue table, and then a background process, written in C# or PowerShell or VBScript or what have you, that wakes up every n seconds or minutes, and checks for any new tasks in the queue table?